# Laravel get Session with javascript while loading

Tags: javascript, php, session, laravel

Here is my scenario:

-I'm processing an excel file that'll took about ~10 minute

-While processing, I want to send a feedback to user that we are currently processing

My idea was using Session that will put value while processing, and get that Session using javascript in current view

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("progress");
        setInterval(
            function(){
                element.innerHTML = "{{Session::get('progress')}}";
            },500
        );
    });
</script>
```

And somewhere in my controller, let's just say like this:

```
    $i = 0;
    while(!$done){
        processingComplicated();
        Session::put('progress', $i);
        Session::save();
    }
```

And my basic view :

```
<div id="progress">0</div>
```

Basically, I want the current page to get the Session data and update the view(id="progress"), but the it won't change.

Can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: It can't be done the way you want - you'll need to have the page reload in order to actually get fresh session data. A lot of people do this using an iframe or using AJAX - the main point is that you need to actually load the PHP file to get the updated value, you can't just put the session var in your page somewhere and expect it to magically update without updating the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AJAX` to update the view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $.get( "processing-status", function( data ) {
                 element.innerHTML = data;
            });
        },500
    );
});
```

And in your routes, controller or wherever you want

```
Route::get('/processing-status', function()
{
    return Session::get('progress');
});
```

Comment: Are you still doing the Session::put ? If you access to /processing-status with debug what doest it display?

Comment: "0"
And it's correct, since I put 
Session::put('progress', 0);
Session::save();
before rendering the uploading page.,
I think there is a problem with the script.,

Comment: Glad it works, did you change it in the $.get or in the route? To edit my answer :)